# How to send av1 encoded stream to a mediamtx server?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

I want to test streaming av1 encoded video from the command line but I don't have enough expertise to know if I'm doing something wrong or if it's simply unsupported.

So far I've tried `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! av1enc ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/usbcamera` and `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video1 -c:v libsvtav1 -an -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/usbcamera`

Using a file source with ffmpeg works with `ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i av1noaudio.mp4 -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/usbcamera` but not with `gstreamer gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=av1noaudio.mp4 ! videoconvert !  rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/usbcamera`

Comment: For future visitors:
Ffmpeg currently does not support streaming in rtp of av1.
This includes AV1. The line he wrote (ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i av1noaudio.mp4 -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/usbcamera) transcodes the av1 feed to mpeg4, which is sent to the rtsp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=Videos/av1noaudio.mp4 ! qtdemux ! av1parse ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/usbcamera`

I don't know if this is the most optimal solution, but at least it'll help any other newbie coming behind me.